# iOS - Adding actions to remote notifications. What am I missing?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I'm trying to add an action to the iOS remote notification.

This is the command I'm sending to houston (https://github.com/nomad/houston)

```
apn push "APNS_TOKEN_HERE" -c /Users/johannwerner/Desktop/apple_push_notification.pem -P '{"aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":"OK","title":"hello","body":"Hello"},"category":"ACTIONABLE"}}'
```

When the app launches from the push notification and I log launchOptions from the didFinishWithOptions method I get the following

```
{
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey =     {
        aps =         {
            alert =             {
                "action-loc-key" = OK;
                body = Hello;
                title = hello;
            };
            category = ACTIONABLE;
        };
    };
}
```

When I'm registering the notification in the code I'm using the following.

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UNUserNotificationCenter")) {

    UNNotificationAction* snoozeAction = [UNNotificationAction
                                          actionWithIdentifier:@"SNOOZE_ACTION"
                                          title:@"Snooze"
                                          options:UNNotificationActionOptionNone];

    UNNotificationCategory* generalCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
                                               categoryWithIdentifier:@"GENERAL"
                                               actions:@[snoozeAction]
                                               intentIdentifiers:@[@"ACTIONABLE"]
                                               options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];



    UNAuthorizationOptions options = (UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound |UNAuthorizationOptionAlert);
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

    [center setNotificationCategories:[NSSet setWithObjects:generalCategory, nil]];

    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if( !error ){
             [Localytics didRequestUserNotificationAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                                                                    granted:granted];
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
         }

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PUSH_DELEGATE_AFTER_REGISTERED  object: nil];
     }];
}
```

I'm getting a push that has my title and body text of "hello" but there is no button or action on the push notification.

I'm been through this guide https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/

as well as apples documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1 for the payload

and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html for adding actions to the notification.

Comment: Press on the notification to get the buttons, it doesn't show directly.

Comment: I have pushed on notification or swiped left to press view but no other buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it. In my payload I was sending category as string "actionable". It should be "GENERAL"